# SharePoint 2010 PowerShell command get required parameters

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am new to powershell and I want to validate a tricky rule.
Let's assume I enter **Get-SPSite** as command and it may have required params as well. Assume **Identity** is required Params for **Get-SPSite** command.
I want to do programming as shown below scenario.

```
If(requiredParams.Contains(-Identity))
{
//do stuff
}
else
{
//do stuff
}
```

Any possibility in powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will show you which are marked mandatory -

```
(gcm Get-SPSite).Parameters.GetEnumerator() | 
   % {if ($_.Value.Attributes.Mandatory) {$_.Key}}
```

But this doesn't account for which parameter set is in use.

Another possible way

```
(help Get-SPSite).Parameters | select -exp parameter | 
    % {if ($_.Required -eq 'true') {$_.name}}
```

Comment: Any idea about this error:   The term 'more.com' is not recognized as the name of a
 file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
cluded, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: I just enter this command in powershell: (help Get-SPSite).Parameters | select -exp parameter | % {if ($_.Required -eq 'true') {$_.name}}

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally worked. (gcm Get-SPSite).Parameters.GetEnumerator() | % { 
    Write-Host "Key: $($_.key)"
}

Comment: Is this only works for SharePoint cmdlets? I have tried the same format for NWAdmin.exe commands. But not working.

Comment: @SivakumarPiratheeban this is only for powershell cmdlets